# GRUB very slow after changes in partitions

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I moved my logical partitions recently (see [Disk operations freeze Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/101640/disk-operations-freeze-debian) for details), and all works fine after the change. However as a weird side-effect GRUB started to take really long to load, e.g. it takes >10s to move from the black screen with Loading Grub message to the list of available kernels. Any ideas how to fix it?

I am using GRUB 2 from Debian testing.

Comment: I had the same problem with Ubuntu Karmic...unfortunately I don't have an answer for you, but the upgrade to Lucid fixed it (that's an upgrade from 1.97Beta4 to 1.98).